# WSJT software on 12.04 verses version 10

Tags: 12.04

Dear Support Ubuntu support community:

I recently upgraded my pc from Ubuntu version 10.04 to 12.  I had a program running under 10.04 called WSJT; it was installed via Synaptic pkg mgr.

After I upgraded to version 12.04, when I run WSJT from the command line, or via the graphical user interface, the program starts, seems to come all the way up and then, collapses.

Is there anything I can do to keep the WSJT running?  It is a most excellent program.

Please let me know and thank you.

Comment: I notice that you un-accepted my answer. Was the software I located not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it dropped out of the official repositories or you had a special PPA at the time, but I located what I believe is the program you're referring to.

https://launchpad.net/%7Ejnogatch/+archive/wsjtx

There is a release for 12.04 Precise there that you can download, and also instructions for adding their PPA to your `apt` list.